# Solving a cubic congruence equation with Chinese Remainder Theorem

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, cryptography, chinese-remainder-theorem

I have the following congruence equation: $x^{3} \equiv 3 \bmod(357035)$ which I'm having troubles solving.

The prime factorisation of $35705$ is $5\cdot 7 \cdot 101^{2}$. I thought I would solve the congruences \begin{align}x^{3} & \equiv 3 \bmod(5) \\ x^{3} & \equiv 3 \bmod(7) \\ x^{3} & \equiv 3 \bmod(101^{2})\end{align} using the Chinese Remainder Theorem, but I somehow ended up with the solution $x^{3} \equiv 3 \bmod(357035)$ which doesn't help me. Some hints or a detailed answer would be much appreciated.

Comment: You're right, that's wrong. That was sloppy of me, I'll make an edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not my strong suit, but just by testing, it appears the second condition is impossible.  If $x\equiv0\pmod7, x^3\equiv0\pmod7$.  Otherwise, by Fermat's Little Theorem

$$x^6\equiv1\pmod7$$
$$(x^3+1)(x^3-1)\equiv0\pmod7$$
$$x^3\equiv-1,1\pmod7$$

Therefore, there are no solutions.

Comment: Maybe I'm just slow today, but how did you arrive at $x \equiv 0 \bmod(7)$?

Comment: @Auclair I think you missed the "if".  If $x$ is a multiple of $7$, so is $x^3$.

Comment: Of course, yes I did miss it. Thank you, it makes much more sense to me now.

Answer (score 2):

It is easy verify that the cubes of $\mathbb {Z/7Z}$=$\mathbb F_7$ are just the $3$ elements $0,1,-1$. Hence $x^3\equiv 3$ has no solution.